# MongoDB aggregation pipeline : using $cond to return a $match stage?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to build queries to have actually interesting ways to interact with a database. One of them is to search for documents in a certain range of years. My thinkingnwas to build an aggregation pipeline where I check if the year range have been selected in the search form, then return the matching documents. If no range is selected, then return all the documents and go to the next stage of the aggregation pipeline.

Here is what I have tried (there's only one stage in the `aggregate` because i haven't managed to make this first one work, yet) :

```js
    db.collection('archives').aggregate([
      { $cond: { if: yearStart.length === 4 && yearEnd === 4 },
        then: { $match:
          { $and:
            [
              { year: {$gte: yearStart} },
              { year: {$lte: yearEnd} }
            ]
          }
        },
        else: { $match: {} }
      }
    ]).toArray( (err, docs) => {
      if (err) throw (err)
      res.json(docs)
    })
```

So, this doesn't work. I get the error `MongoError: A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field.`. So I thought it was just a matter of enclosing the `$cond` statement in curlies. But nope. I get a full on `unexpected token {` crash at this. So I'm thinkning that maybe `$cond` aren't meant to be used like this (returning `$match` stages). I'm inclined to think so, as the documentation only shows an example returning a simple value... Is it right?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Aggregation pipeline is a pipeline. The unconditional one. Save the "*if the year range have been selected in the search form*" logic for application layer, and perform different queries, depending on user input.

Answer (score 2):

Create the query object to be used with **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** outside the pipeline first with native JavaScript conditionals as using the **[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)** operator is only applicable within specified pipeline stages. Here you are using
it as a pipeline step hence the error thrown.

Consider the following:

```
const query = { "year": { } };
if (yearStart.length === 4 && yearEnd === 4) {
    query["year"]["$gte"] = yearStart;
    query["year"]["$lte"] = yearEnd;    
}

db.collection('archives').aggregate([ { "$match": query } ]).toArray((err, docs) => {
    if (err) throw (err);
    res.json(docs);
});
```

Or using the **[`find()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#find)** method as

```
db.collection('archives').find(query).toArray((err, docs) => {
    if (err) throw (err);
    res.json(docs);
});
```